# Mediterranean sailing times/distances

Tags: geography

I can't find an answer on the internet.How long would it take to sail from Tunisia to Monaco, then to Coruna, Spain?  This would be done using sails and rowing power only.

Comment: This Stack Exchange concerns itself with the details of developing fictional worlds (fantasy or SF). I can't see any way in which we could interpret your question as being about world building. There may be a sailing Stack Exchange, if so, that would be the place to ask your question.

Comment: http://orbis.stanford.edu/